# Can the WAN IP address be retrieved programmatically from a DD-WRT router

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I currently query an external server for my external IP address, but I should really query my own router.  It would limit the traffic to the LAN, and the router certainly knows what the address is.  Does anybody know if there's a concise way of querying the router (other than screen scraping the status page).  Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do with it. Are you looking for a powershell script, vbscript script, bash script, python script, ect... Your platform and how you plan on using the info will greatly affect answers.

Comment: Are you comfortable using SNMP?

Comment: If the router itself is behind NAT, it may not know its own external IP address.

Comment: @Bandrami Yes, SNMP would have been the "correct" way, but more complex than my eventual solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an acceptable solution.  Request page
`http://router_ip/Status_Internet.live.asp`
from your dd_wrt router (it needs authentication). This output is not dependent on the GUI style, since it is only the auto-refresh data.  It's very easy to extract the IP address from the returned data.

Answer (score 3):

in console, run "nvram get wan_ipaddr"

Comment: this is not easily done with a program.

Comment: @erict It looks pretty concide to me. Please make your requirements clearer.

Comment: @David As the title indicates, I want to do this programmatically.  My requirements are that I have a server that wants to know the external internet address, even though it is NATed through a DD-WRT router.  I was querying an external server like whatismyip.com, but wanted a solution that doesn't depend on external sources.  I eventually found that I can query the DD-WRT router's page called Status_Internet.live.asp which returns a bunch of info, including the WAN IP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install php, if it isn't already installed.
Make a floder.
Make a php internal webserver -- the one built in.
Let it return the ouput from

```
ifconfig |grep "inet addr" |cut -d: -f2 |cut -d" " -f1
```

It will return all the ip addresses it has (internal, external and loopback). You can then poll this instead of the external server.

Comment: wouldn't work -- need the external IP on the other side of a router (specifically a DD-WRT router).  Your suggestion would return the local IP addresses